# Cache Mediator wso2 esb api

Tags: caching, wso2-esb

I have created an API in wso2 esb to call the rest-service. I have used cache mediator, it's working fine for a normal `GET` method.

What i want is, I have used a `GET` Method to get the employee details, I will be passing the employee_id with the url.

This API call is hitting the service for the first time for a given employee_id, then for next call for the same employee_id it should get the response from the cache itself up-to the given Timeout period. if i change the employee_id then it should hit the service but it is getting the response from the cache. for different employee_id also.

My API is,

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="cacheApi" context="/cacheApi">
<resource methods="GET" uri-template="/{id}/">
  <inSequence>
     <log/>
     <cache id="" scope="per-host" collector="false" hashGenerator="org.wso2.carbon.mediator.cache.digest.DOMHASHGenerator" timeout="60">
        <implementation type="memory" maxSize="10"/>
     </cache>
     <send>
        <endpoint>
           <http method="GET" uri-template="http://localhost:8080/rest-services/services/employee/{uri.var.id}"/>
        </endpoint>
     </send>
  </inSequence>
  <outSequence>
     <cache scope="per-host" collector="true"/>
     <send/>
  </outSequence>
</resource>
</api>
```

My API call will be as,

```
http://localhost:8280/cacheApi/1
http://localhost:8280/cacheApi/2
http://localhost:8280/cacheApi/3
....
```

Can anyone help me to solve this??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement your own hash generator (implementing  `org.wso2.carbon.mediator.cache.digest.DigestGenerator`) since `org.wso2.carbon.mediator.cache.digest.DOMHASHGenerator` hash is only based on the the body of the request / `msgContext.getEnvelope().getBody()` and won't work for your API.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new implementation of the hash generator that you can try, which uses the API URI as well for generating the hash value.

In order to apply that, set the hash generator to `org.wso2.carbon.mediator.cache.digest.REQUESTHASHGenerator`.

Now your cache mediator should like this,

```
<cache id="" scope="per-host" collector="false" hashGenerator="org.wso2.carbon.mediator.cache.digest.REQUESTHASHGenerator" timeout="60">
        <implementation type="memory" maxSize="10"/>
</cache>
```

(PS: I only tested this for the WSO2 ESB 4.9.0 release.)