# how to cache RESTful requests and JSON responses using wso2 ESB

Tags: api, caching, wso2, mediator, wso2-esb

what wso2 mediator and package classes implement JSON/REST/HTTP friendly caching? For example, read HTTP headers and URIs to identify cache keys on GET commands, parse JSON (instead of XML) to invalidate cache entry on collection POSTs (with key in payload), and conform with standard HTTP/1.1 header scheme (i.e. https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html ) ??

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Cache Mediator` from WSO2 ESB.

```
<sequence name="SEQ_CACHE">
  <in>
    <cache scope="per-host"
      collector="false"
      hashGenerator="org.wso2.caching.digest.DOMHASHGenerator"
      timeout="20">
      <implementation type="memory" maxSize="100"/>
    </cache>

    <send>
      <endpoint>
        <address uri="http://localhost:9000/services/SimpleStockQuoteService"/>
      </endpoint>
    </send>
  </in>

  <out>
    <cache scope="per-host" collector="true"/>
    <send/>
  </out>
</sequence>
```

Comment: Waqas, i explicitly mentioned REST and JSON. SimpleStockQuoteService uses XML and SOAP. the sample is not applicable.

Comment: It is just a sample. I believe that WSO2 ESB Cache mediator can be applicable for JSON as well. Have you tried that?

Comment: I have tried the WSO2 ESB cache mediator, which does not work. the query string parameter is not triggering a new, distinct DOMHash.  a new URI is not triggering a new, distinct DOMHash.

Comment: this question is similar to to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35150859/cache-mediator-wso2-esb-api      , which also remains unsolved